# For all positive integers n, the square root of n is irrational if and only if the square root of n$^3$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove: For all positive integers n, the $\sqrt\ n$ is irrational if and only if $\sqrt \ n$$^3$ is irrational.

Having a lot of trouble with this, any help is greatly appreciated. Right now I'm trying to prove the contrapositive but not getting anywhere with that.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{n^3}=n\sqrt n$.

Comment: Also use the fact that square root of $n$ is rational (actually integer) iff in the factorization into prime powers $n=\prod_j p_j^{a_j}$  all the $a_j$'s  are even integers.

Comment: Thank you David! That tip helped a lot and I think I have a proof that is good enough.